# Debian / Kerio is ARP storming my ISP after loosing connection to the gateway

Tags: networking, linux-networking, ethernet, arp

The problem: after Kerio Control (Debian) lost connection to the gateway it starts sending ARP like for "who has 8.8.8.8?" in such frequency, that the gateway gets shut down due to packet inspection my ISP has configured on their port. Of course I am on different subnet than Google, so why it makes such attempts if the route is not accessible instead of just waiting? How to prevent this or at least limit? I can't use stuff like arptables or ebtables and tc seems a bit too difficult.
Thanks!

```
/etc # ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:XY:XZ:40:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.16/16 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:XX:XY:40:0f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 178.XY.XZ.230/30 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

/etc # ip r
default via 178.XY.XZ.229 dev eth1
10.0.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.16
```

Comment: who-has 8.8.8.8 makes no sense. Would suggests some incorrect netmask in your network configuration. Reaching 8.8.8.8, the only ARP you should see is a who-has for your gateway address, which in turn would route this accordingly.

Comment: Exactly- doesn't make sense! So why is it doing that? How to stop that? My netmask is 255.255.255.252. I am seeing such absurd attempts in case packets can't be routed to the internet.

Comment: Oh, and I have static public ipv4 set to that interface and ISP's gateway has public ip address too.

Comment: Can you show us a little bit about your network configuration? `ip a` and `ip r`?

Comment: @SYN and A.B thank you guys, I edited my questions to give you the details.

Comment: @A.B doesnt seem that is my case (via is present)

Comment: @A.B ip rule - I have checked tables local and main, they are ok. ip monitor is a nice tip (ts command not found, but this is likely for timestamp, no not a big issue). Still this seem to me like a glitch in the system not a misconfiguration.